# junit Mock a method of AbstractService in a ChildService

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I hava a TaskService who extends an AbstractService.

In the abstractService, I have a method getCurrentUserRoleEntity used by differents methods accross the services. This method uses a repository to find the current role.

In my task service, I have a method to find the tasks for the current user role and the the category,
this method has 2 parameters, the caegoryId and the method getCurrentUserRoleEntity.

```
public List<Task> findTaskByCategoryIdForCurrentUserRole(Long categoryId) {
    return vTacheAffaireRepository.findTaskByCategoryIdForCurrentUserRoleOrderByEcheanceAscTacheIdAsc(categoryId, getCurrentUserRoleEntity().getId())
        .stream().map(vTaskMapper::toDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

When I test the rest ressource who call the service, I would like to mock the getCurrentUserRoleEntity to use my test entity instead of use the real method.

I tried differents approachs but none answer my need.
Have you an idea of how mock this method during the rest test?

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you just mock the repository used by the superclass?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple approach would be, you can create a setter and getter for getCurrentUserRoleEntity() method by which you can insert your mock object instance instead of real one.

Comment: Indeed, I could encapsulate the method from the abstract class in the method into the service but it means I will create some extra code only used by the unit test. Actually I would like to do something like Mockito.when(AbstractService::getCurrentUserRoleEntity).thenReturn(myMockuserRoleEntity);

Comment: Yes, indeed that is a good idea by which you could avoid the boilerplate code.

This gist matches your scenario, 

https://gist.github.com/victortyau/e805ab2bbce1696fcc0579407d3a171e

Comment: TasckService taskServiceMock = Mockito.mock(TaskService.class, CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
when(taskService.getCurrentUserRoleEntity()).thenReturn(userRoleEntity); 
Problem with this, I have a null pointer. When I look in debug, the null pointer comes from the method in the abstract class and the debug shows "userRoleRepository = 'this' is not available". Why it goes trough the method instead of returning the value?

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet of that abstract class?

Comment: public abstract class AbstractService {@Autowired UserRoleRepository userRoleRepository; public UserRoleEntity getCurrentUserRoleEntity() { return userRoleRepository.findByUserAndRole( userRepository.findByName(getCurrentUserLogin()), roleRepository.findByName(getCurrentUserRoleName().orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("User role not found", "user-role.not-found"))) ); } }

Answer (score -1):

Try overriding that method in the test, given your method is public you can define a new class called  `TestTaskService`

```
TestTaskService extends TaskService {
@Override
public List<Task> findTaskByCategoryIdForCurrentUserRole(Long categoryId) {
//provide mock implementation 
}

}
```